# Adding to a list via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, bluej

```
public class Test
{
    private ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    private void addToList(Object o)
    {
        list.add(o);
    }
}
```

If i call the method `addToList(Object o)` from an external class via reflection, is there something I need to take in to account in order for the reflection call to be able to access the list?

```
BMethod method = builderClass.getDeclaredMethod("addToList", new Class<?>[]{Object.class});
```

I am using the BlueJ api which is similar to reflection in Java but wraps the objects hence the BMethod.

I was just wondering if the method needs to have some reference to the arraylist as it cant see it via the reflection call

Thanks

I have managed to solve this. For those that want to no the answer - the method i was invoking, i added the code to reflectively get the internal field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `method.setAccessible(true)` on the `Method` object

Comment: thats annoying, a BMethod doesnt have that available :(

Comment: In that case, switch to a decent IDE and get rid of BlueJ

Comment: I am developing an extension for BlueJ in eclipse :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do something like that, but it should work

1. Retrieve the method (which you already have)
2. Make it [accessible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5b%5d,%20boolean%29) which allows you to invoke the method, although it is private
3. [Invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) the method